# Loop by a jquery function which result is handled outside the loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsfiddle

Just found some interesting code in jsfiddle and tried to loop and get multiple competitions/teams data in a single run.

I would like to request the following feed multiple times (in a loop):

```
var f = new $jqOpta.FeedRequest(
  $jqOpta.FeedRequest.FEED_F30,
  r.feedParams, // feed params like competition, season, etc.
  dataDef, // result handler object
  r.feedLife, // feed life ??
  r.trn, // trn, maybe translation ??
  r); // request object
// finally request feed
$jqOpta.FeedMonitor.requestFeed(f);
```

The full code is here (and is not mine, btw):
https://jsfiddle.net/t4ywc8vt/10/

I've tried a for loop calling the request multiple times but no results because "dataDef.done" is not called to handle the request result as if the request is outside the for loop. Do you see a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You have to learn first the basics, before you try to analyze source code from other developers.
It is not a loop, just a simple instantiation of an given object.
For example:

```
var f = new $jqOpta.FeedRequest($jqOpta.FeedRequest.FEED_F30, r.feedParams, c.dataDef, r.feedLife, r.trn, trn, r);
[[var f = new ]]$jqOpta.FeedMonitor.requestFeed(f);
```

Comment: How is this going to get results from multiple competitions/teams? I need to "requestFeed" multiple times, but how?